# Did Yuzuru ultimately cause Hatsune's death?

Tags: angel-beats

Yuzuru Otonashi's sister Hatsune had cancer and there were indications that it was getting worse. When Christmas came, the doctors refused to let her out but keeping his word Yuzuru snuck in and took her out.

When we seem them together outside and when Yuzuru talks to her, she seems very weak and Yuzuru monologue's saying he continued to have a one-sided conversation. The next scene we see is Yuzuru is being asked if he is ok following Hatsune's death.

I am wondering, while Hatsune was probably bound to be killed by her cancer later on, was Yuzuru taking Hatsune out that night what caused her cancer to kill her ?

Comment: I searched on the net and cold does in fact accentuate cancer but not sure to what degree as well as if Otonashi's sister disease gravity would lead to her end with or without that trip

Answer (score 1):

Hatsune, like you have said, is already suffering from cancer. Did Yuzuru worsen it? Yes and No. We can take this in different point of view as everything like in the world, doesn't have just one answer.

1. **The Positive POV**:
   Yuzuru helped Hatsune more than could have ever hoped for. As we all know, she was slowly dying from cancer and judging by everything, it might even be uncurable. I'm figuring, Yuzuru did help her...a lot. As you may know, living aimlessly and slowly dying is a painful experience more so than death. The little girl got cancer, something that, from her age, couldn't just begin to grasp. I'm wondering how she faced it, but we already know how she dealt with it. Yuzuru, giving her manga daily/weekly? was enough of a drive for her to keep on going. It doesn't matter if the mangas he gave had contuinity. Just the manga itself would suffice. What really sealed the deal was the promise.
   Yuzuru promised Hatsune to go at the night of Christmas, something that she has always been looking forward for dearly and it became true. I think dying happily and achieving your dreams is a great kind of deal.
2. **The Negative POV**: Yuzuru really did indirectly fasten her death. With her debilitating health and added up with the cold weather, even against the doctor wishes, he still did it. Yuzuru caused Hatsune's death is somewhat true. Even if her death is sooner or later that we can ponder upon, those prescious days/weeks? are still important.

All-in-all, we can go by these two POV. I'll go with a POV. The satisfaction was enough to give for someone he loved. Yuzuru gave the best memory Hatsune could ever wish for. Spend the night of Christmas with his older brother rather than dying a slow and painful death. **So, it's up to you to decide**.

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se]. I noticed you have a number of activities on Stack Overflow, but anyway consider taking a quick [tour] to know what's on-topic or not here. Also, I edited the last sentence on your answer since SE is not a discussion/social site (the prompt feels too chatty).

Comment: Haha, thanks for the edit. I'll try to correct this habit of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's tricky, she didn't seem to be on the last few days (she would've been on artificial ventilation otherwise) but we're not even told what kind of cancer she had, some can take months to kill a person even on the terminal stage, others can very well just end in less than a month, even days, but even then we can never tell, doctors give you a tentative life expectancy but that's to be taken with extreme caution. Taking her out in was definitely NOT a good idea, but it wouldn't have outright killed her unless she was a few days away from dying, and definitely wouldn't have been peaceful. In her weakness and the cold she'd have entered a severe coughing fit or ventilation issues, entered respiratory disfunction and pass away slowly and painfully, but Yuzuru would have enough time to bring her back to the hospital to get her intubated. So her passing away peacefully, I'd dare say it just was her time to go, and Yuzuru was a great brother for trying to fulfill his promise in her last moments.